# How to compare two System.Drawing.Icon items

Tags: c#, comparison, icons

I am trying to fill a treeview in WPF with icons of files and folders, just like Windows Explorer does. The problem is, that it is very slow to load, because I am using a converter that just calls

```
return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, new Int32Rect(0, 0, c.Width, c.Height), BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

I assume that this creates a new icon for every file/folder I get. I retrieve the images with the `ManagedWinAPI` extension. So now, I was planning on using a Dictionary that can compare the Icons against each other.

But how can I compare two `System.Drawing.Icon` objects? Because the reference is always different (tested). I don't need a pixel comparator, because I don't think that will speed up my process.

**Update**

Taking *@Roy Dictus'* answer into account, the dictionary still tells me that there are no equal objects in the list:

```
Dictionary<byte[], ImageSource> data = new Dictionary<byte[], ImageSource>();

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Icon c = (Icon)value;
    Bitmap bmp = c.ToBitmap();

    // hash the icon
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] rawIcon = converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[])) as byte[];

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(rawIcon);

    ImageSource result;

    data.TryGetValue(hash, out result);

    if (result == null)
    {
        PrintByteArray(hash); // custom method, prints the same values for two folder icons
        result = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(c.Handle, new Int32Rect(0, 0, c.Width, c.Height), BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        data.Add(hash, result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found equal icons");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: how do you know which icon to load?

Comment: There *must* be a more efficient means of accessing/converting the icon than using `CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon`. That's intended for working with unmanaged icon data.

Comment: @Damien I haven't found one, this seems to be one to take it to a WFP ImageSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to either compare the bitmaps, or calculate hash values based on the bitmaps and then compare those.

[This post](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-hash2.php) on Visual C# Kicks shows you how to calculate a hash value from a bitmap.

**EDIT:** Some extra information based on how OP modified his question:

I wouldn't use byte[] as the dictionary key -- I'm not sure that implements IComparable. If you can convert the byte array to a string, which does implement IComparable, then it would probably work.

You can convert a byte array to a string like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(result[i].ToString("X2"));
}
```

Comment: Nice article! The hashing does seem to give the same byte[] for two icons that are the same. But somehow, my dictionary still says that the key is not in the list. I will post my complete conversion method in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `icon.Handle` as dictionary key.

Comment: Already tried this, but it seems that these are different too (even for two folders).